# iPhone Warning...!! App running in simulator not in Iphone device...!

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, jailbreak, cydia

I am new to iphone programming. Now I am working for a project which in combination of opengl and objective c.It is working perfectly in simulator but while running in device its showing the following warnings

```
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Library/MobileSubstrate/MobileSubstrate.dylib (file         not found).
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Library/Frameworks/CydiaSubstrate.framework/Libraries/SubstrateLoader.dylib (file not found).
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
```

Only the splash screen is coming .How to remove these warnings?

Anyone can help me please???

Answer (score 0):

Your phone is jailbroken, that could be causing the issue or it could be something else.

You should use breakpoints to figure out exactly where your code is crashing